# Poisson summation from $n=1$ to $\infty $

Tags: summation, fourier-transform, laplace-transform, dirac-delta

If we accept this as valid Proof of Poisson summation

$\displaystyle  \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\hat {f}(t) dt= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f (t)e^{-2 i \pi n t} dt=  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f (t)\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-2 i \pi n t} dt = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f (t)\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta (t-n) dt=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f (t)\delta (t-n) dt=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}f (n)$

Let's use fact that $ \int_{a}^{\infty}f (t)\delta (t-n)=f (n)$, if $a <n $ and $ \int_{a}^{\infty}f (t)\delta (t-n)=0$, if $a>n $

$\displaystyle   \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{0^+}^{\infty}f (t)e^{-2 i \pi n t} dt=  \int_{0^+}^{\infty}f (t)\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-2 i \pi n t} dt = \int_{0^+}^{\infty}f (t)\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta (t-n) dt=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{0^+}^{\infty}f (t)\delta (t-n) dt=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f (n) \wedge \displaystyle   \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{0^-}^{\infty}f (t)e^{-2 i \pi n t} dt= \left[...\right] =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f (n)$

Ergo

$\displaystyle  \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \mathcal{L} \{ f \} (2 \pi i n)= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}f (t)e^{-2 i \pi n t} dt=\frac {f (0)}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f (n)$

And the question is. Is this so trivial that no one is talking about it or people just missed it. I mean at this [article](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.peertechzpublications.com/articles/AMP-5-141.pdf&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjDor-tpNb9AhXX_yoKHYGHAC4QFnoECAQQAg&usg=AOvVaw2L5byXDO356phO20CxHXRS) author is confused to about the status of equation (he get a little different form)

Comment: I do not accept this as a valid proof, no. It is maybe a motivating heuristic to present, to explain to students why we might think this is true, but it is no proof in my opinion. I've never really "done" Fourier analysis though, so perhaps all steps are correct. It looks sketchy though

Comment: I'm thinking similarly, so this is the reason I wrote 'If we accept it as valid proof of Poisson summation'. But it seems that it is accepted by mathematictions. I'm asking about that because I was trying to proof that theorem by 2 mounths (and I almost did it with one problem about $\frac {f (0)}{2}$. But when I used dirac delta function (for the first time in life), it took me just few minutes

Comment: $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{-2\pi int}$$Does not actually converge so any proof must very carefully handle such a thing

Comment: Yes, but it seems to be no problem. I mean, I started with dirac delta function just tooday. And everything seems to be fine for others. This is my take on the theorem without dirac delta function but it's still have issue somewhere. I shouldn't 'leave it as proof' XD https://mathoverflow.net/questions/442304/frac-f-02-sum-k-1-inftyf-k-sum-n-infty-infty-mathcall?_gl=1*m1demk*_ga*MTI4OTg2NDQ0My4xNjY5NDk3MDkz*_ga_S812YQPLT2*MTY3OTkzOTM4Mi4zOTguMS4xNjc5OTQ4MjU3LjAuMC4w